# Equvalent Asymptote of Radical Functions Proof

Tags: calculus

There a formula in our textbook which we can find a radical function's slant asymptote as it goes to + or - infinity.

I couldn't find It's proof anywhere on the internet As I couldnt find the formula itself.

when $$\lim_{x\to \infty} (ax^n+bx^{n-1}+...)^{1/n} $$
is equvalent to :

$$(a)^{1/n} |{x+\frac{b}{na}}| $$

Comment: Why wouldn't it blow up to $\pm \infty$ (depending on the value of $a$, and which solution to $1/n$ you want)? Are you taking the limit as $n$ goes to infinity perhaps?

Comment: @Logician6 it does go to $\infty$.  Notice that the expression for the limit has an $x$ term, and remember that $x \to \infty$.  We're looking for a slant asymptote, not a hard limit.

Comment: Oh...slant asymptote, gotchya!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of this is that, if $P(x)=c_1x^d + c_2 x^{d-1} ... $ is some polynomial function of degree $d$ such that $\lim_{x \to \infty}\left({P(x) \over x^{d-1}}\right)^n= \lim_{x \to \infty}ax^n+bx^{n-1} \dots$, then clearly we have ${c_1}^n=a$ and $n{c_1}^{n-1}c_2=b.$ Your equivalence follows.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that two functions are slant asymptotic if and only if the limit of their ratio goes to 1. So I believe what you're *really* trying to show is that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(ax^n+bx^{n-1}+\dots)^\frac{1}{n}}{a^{1/n}|x+\frac{b}{na}|}=1.
\end{align*}
Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

I just Proved it with the bionomial expansion of 
$ (x+b)^n $ .

The whole idea is that $x^{n} $ and $x^{n-1}$ make the big changes and we shoudn't consider others Which I can't compeletly understand.

I would appreciate it if someone could tell me why we're ignoring $x^{n-2}$ and so on.

Comment: See my answer.  If you view the root as $P(x) \over {x^{d-1}}$, where $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $d$, the remaining terms are $O(x^{-1})$ which vanishes as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: @GabrielBurns I can't still quite get why $ cx^{n-2} $ is ignored

Comment: If $P(x)=c_1x^d+c_2x^{d-1}+c_3x^{d-2}\dots$ then ${P(x)\over{x^{d-1}}}=c_1x+c_2+c_3x^{-1}\dots$.   If ${P(x)\over{x^{d-1}}}^n=ax^n+bx^{n-1}+cx^{n-2}\dots,$ then $a$ and $b$ can be written in terms of $c_1$ and $c_2$ only, meaning that $c_1$ and $c_2$ can be written in terms of just $a$ and $b$.  Because ${{c_3x^{d-2}+\dots}\over {x^{d-1}}}=O(x^{-1})$, $c_1$ and $c_2$ are all we need to know to determine the asymptotic behavior of $\left(ax^n+bx^{n-1}+cx^{n-2}\dots\right)^{1\over n}={P(x)\over {x^{d-1}}}.$